# How to do Spring MVC redirect to an {...} like url

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to execute the following code

```
public String login(LoginForm loginForm, BindingResult result) {
    ...
    return "redirect:" + redirectUri;
}
```

where `redirectUri` can have a form like {111-111}. Is does not matter that it's not a url indeed - the redirect will be caught and properly handled.
The problem is that Spring tries to parse 111-111 as a parameter and throws an exception.

Is there a way to force redirect without such parsing? Maybe use another approach instead of "redirect:" prefix?

Comment: Try returning a `return new RedirectView(redirectUri)`

Comment: Thanks Arun, but it doesn't help. Because returning a "redirect:..." string actually does the same - it creates a `RedirectView`.

Comment: can you provide a sample redirect url? and also the controller that is supposed to service the redirected url?

Comment: {111-111} - this is a sample of redirected url. There's no controller to handle teh redirect. The client is mobile device which is catching redirects and doing its own stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here:

[Redirect to dynamic URL in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311940/redirect-to-dynamic-url-in-spring-mvc)

I just needed to do this

```
public void login(LoginForm loginForm, BindingResult result, 
    HttpServletResponse response) {
    ...
    response.sendRedirect(redirectUri);
}
```