# How to do a redirect in Spring MVC controller?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying use a PRG (Post-Redirect-Get) pattern in one of my Spring MVC controller. The controller collects user data from an HTML form, does some processing, stores data in DB and then shows a JSP page. After saving data a redirect should happen and then the JSP page should be displayed.

I also tried to prepend "redirect:" in front of the VIEW_NAME but I get 404 then.

Please guide.

**CartPageController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/cartPageController.do")
public class CartPageController {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(CartPageController.class);
    private static final String VIEW_NAME = "cart";

    @Autowired
    protected MasterDao masterDao;

    @RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public ModelAndView processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        LOG.debug("Into the CartPageController...");

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

        //create Cart object and store it in session
        Cart cart = null;
        if (session.getAttribute("cart") != null) {
            cart = (Cart) session.getAttribute("cart");
        } else {
            cart = createCart();
            session.setAttribute("cart", cart);
        }
        LOG.debug("cart = " + cart);

        //determine the cart operation
        String btnAddToCart = GenericUtils.nullToEmptyString(request.getParameter("btnAddToCart"));
        String removeProduct = GenericUtils.nullToEmptyString(request.getParameter("removeProduct"));
        String updateProduct = GenericUtils.nullToEmptyString(request.getParameter("updateProduct"));
        LOG.debug("btnAddToCart = " + btnAddToCart);
        LOG.debug("removeProduct = " + removeProduct);
        LOG.debug("updateProduct = " + updateProduct);
        if (btnAddToCart.length() > 0) {
            addToCart(request, cart);
        } else if (removeProduct.length() > 0) {
            removeProduct(request, cart);
        } else if (updateProduct.length() > 0) {
            updateCart(request, cart);
        }

        //TODO: Should use PRG pattern here
        //TRIED TO APPEND "redirect:" here but does not work, gives me 404 
        mav.setViewName(VIEW_NAME);
        return mav;
    }

    //some more code below here
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect to dynamic URL in Spring MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311940/redirect-to-dynamic-url-in-spring-mvc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should redirect to url not a view name. as [Spring doc says](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-redirecting-redirect-prefix):

> While
>   the use of RedirectView works fine, if the controller itself creates
>   the RedirectView, there is no avoiding the fact that the controller is
>   aware that a redirection is happening. This is really suboptimal and
>   couples things too tightly. The controller should not really care
>   about how the response gets handled. In general it should operate only
>   in terms of view names that have been injected into it.
>
> The special redirect: prefix allows you to accomplish this. If a view
>   name is returned that has the prefix redirect:, the
>   UrlBasedViewResolver (and all subclasses) will recognize this as a
>   special indication that a redirect is needed. **The rest of the view
>   name will be treated as the redirect URL**.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

`return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("/page"));`

Answer (score 0):

You can't just prepend "redirect:" to your view name which results in `redirect:cart` and then obviously `404`, what you have to do for redirect is to specify the redirect path for e.g.:

```
redirect:/cart.htm
```

[This](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-redirectview-example/) should explain it more in details.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way
redirect:cart.do and have requestmapping in controller which will return cart view.
Hope this will work.