# Cross Domain redirection in Spring MVC

Tags: http, spring-mvc, cors

I have been trying to perform a cross domain redirection to (https://www.google.com) from my spring controller as mentioned here ([Redirect to dynamic URL in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311940/redirect-to-dynamic-url-in-spring-mvc)). 
However, I'm getting an error stating that the redirect to the URL has been blocked by CORS policy as the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is not present on the request resource. 
 
How can I fix this error?

Comment: I have already tried adding the header in the HttpServletResponse object - reponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect to third party sites you need to enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). You getting this error bcoz it wouldn’t be allowed under the browser’s same origin policy. Modified your header for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) in the response. You will find more information about Spring CORS support [Here (Spring docs)](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)