# How to redirect on another host in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redirect

I will be grateful for your help :)

I have a frontend on port `4200` and backend on `8080`, and after authentication i redirect it from `8080` to 8080 (another endpoint) to save a new user and after that, I need to redirect to `localhost:4200...`

```
HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.setLocation(Paths.get(url + "/home").toUri());
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .headers(responseHeaders)
                .body(cookie);
```

But I only get a response `There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Illegal char <:> at index 4: http://localhost:4200/home`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
responseHeaders.setLocation(URI.create(url + "/home"));
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FOUND)
                .headers(responseHeaders)
                .body(cookie);
```

It seems that the error occurs at `Paths.get`. If you want to create a `java.net.URI` object, use `URI#create` instead.

I think you make a mistake in setting HTTP status code. If you want to make a redirect response, you have to use `3xx` status code instead of `200`(`ResponseEntity#ok`).

**Related Questions**

[Spring MVC @RestController and redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085295/spring-mvc-restcontroller-and-redirect)
[Redirect to dynamic URL in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311940/redirect-to-dynamic-url-in-spring-mvc)