# Spring Boot RedirectController keeps port for "redirect:/"

Tags: java, node.js, reactjs, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application as backend running on tomcat port `8080` and a reactJS application as frontend running on node port `3000`. For login I redirect from `http://localhost:3000/` to a third party service. Once login is successful it forwards to `http://localhost:8080/private`. Once it forwards to `http://localhost:8080/private`, I want  redirect to `http://localhost:3000/`

I tried to do this with `RedirectController`:

```
@Controller
public class RedirectController {
    @GetMapping("/private")
    public String redirectToRoot() {
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

My `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
   ...
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
```

But instead of redirecting to `http://localhost:3000/` it redirects to `http://localhost:8080/` - so essentially, it keeps the port. How do I change the port from `8080` to `3000`?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to redirect to an absolute URL `redirect:http://localhost:3000` instead of relative URL. You can pass in the target URL using request parameter as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311940/redirect-to-dynamic-url-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks! The only catch for this is to use `redirect:your_url` instead of `redirect:/your_url`.